# CSS - making a div fit the full background image

Tags: html, css

I have a div with some content and want to have a background image. However, I want to be able to see the full height of the image. I could add a load of padding to the top and bottom of the content but I want this to be dynamic for all screen sizes.

```css
div{
  background-image:url(https://via.placeholder.com/350x150);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  /* height 100%; */
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<div> 
Some content
</div>
```

I know I could also just add an `<img>` tag to the `<div>` but there is a lot of content in this that would then have to be floated around to overlay the image.

I don't mind using JS/jQuery to resolve this.

Comment: I know this is kinda backwards usually people ask to get the bg image to fit the div not the div to fit the bg image

Comment: Try `background-size:100% 100%`

Comment: @ZohirSalak thanks for your comment. This will not expand the div as I want but shrink the height of the image so it is distorted

Comment: You need to set a `height` to the `div`or a `min-height`.

Comment: $("#myDiv").css("min-height", ((doc_width/16)*9)+'px'); For an image with aspect ratio (16:9)

Answer (score -1):

To make something fit the full height of the screen instead of using 100% as you would for width, using vh, so in your case:

```
height: 100vh;
```

This will work dynamically depending on the users screen dimensions, you can read more about this as well as see examples [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp).